# Matching an HTML Id with the property of an object

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-objects

I have an HTML list of two vehicles: bike and truck, a form with associated properties ("wheels" and "windows"), and a nested object ("vehicles") that contains the associated values of said properties.

I want to write a function that will take the id of the selected vehicle, match it against the objects within the nested object and then fill the form with the appropriate properties.

For instance if you select "van" from the list, the form fills "wheels" with "2", and windows with "1".

Ideally, the function would be flexible enough to allow for the inclusion of additionally vehicles.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```js
var bikeDetails = {
  wheels: 2,
  windows: 0
};
var vanDetails = {
  wheels: 4,
  windows: 1
};

var vehicles = {
  bike: bikeDetails,
  van: vanDetails
};
```

```html
<div id="classSelectWrapper">
  <form>
    <select id="vehicleList">
      <option value="bike">bike</option>
      <option value="van">van</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</div>


<div class="vehicleDetails">
  <form id="vehicleProps">
    <p>
      <label for="wheels" value="">wheels:</label>
      <input id="wheels" type="text" name="wheels" value="" disabled>
    </p>

    <p>
      <label for="windows">windows:</label>
      <input id="windows" type="text" name="windows" value="" disabled>
    </p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your script could be something like this:

```
var select = document.getElementById('vehicleList');
select.addEventListener('change', function () {
    var selected = this.selectedOptions[0].value,
        wheels = document.getElementById('wheels'),
        windows = document.getElementById('windows');

    wheels.value = vehicles[selected].wheels;
    windows.value = vehicles[selected].windows;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your problem can be implemented like this, hope that it helped you:

```
document.querySelector("#vehicleList").addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  let value = e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].value;
  if(value in vehicles) {
    document.querySelector("#wheels").value = vehicles[value].wheels;
    document.querySelector("#windows").value = vehicles[value].windows;
  }
});
```

Comment: Could you explain the purpose of "e.target" and "options", please?

Comment: To manage the event when it is fired, in our case we use a "change" event for looking for targeted DOM element with the target property to take additional information needed. The options property gives us the array of child options belonging to parent select, in our case an array of length 2. The selectedIndex property is the index of previous array we talked about tha points the selected object, in our case 0 or 1. Note: that every event object has different information thus different properties depending of even type.